# Writing a function m-file in MATLAB

Tags: function, matlab

I am a beginner to coding and I need to write a function.m file for use with Newton's Method. I am having trouble defining the function, where r is radius and p is density:

> ### f(theta) = ((r^2)/2)*((2*pi*p)-(theta - sin(theta)*p))

where radius *r = 30cm* and density *p = 0.82 grams per cm^3*

So far, I have written:

```
function y = f1(theta)
r = 0.3;
p = 0.82;
y = (r^2)/2*(2*pi*p - (theta - sin(theta)*p));
```

Things I am having trouble with:

1. Problem defining r and p. Getting an error:

   ```
   Undefined function or variable 'r'
   ```
2. Having trouble plotting the function.

Things I want to do:

1. Plot the function to see where the roots are.
2. Be able to evaluate the function for a given theta.

All help is appreciated. Thank you!

Comment: Thanks for the response - I had named it something else - sorry for confusion. But question still stands.

Comment: Okay, but is you M-file named `function.m` or `f1.m`? Your question is still inconsistent. Also, please provide the *entire* error message including line numbers. And don't ask two completely different questions in one -pick one.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

i tried your code without changing. i named the **M-file** as **f1** and executed the function in command line it is working.

```
function y = f1(theta)
r = 0.3;
p = 0.82;
y = (r^2)/2*(2*pi*p - (theta - sin(theta)*p));
```

i am getting the output as below

> > f=f1(45)

f =

-1.7618

> > this tells that there is no problem in your function. see for some other reason. if you could give your whole code it would be better to diagnose.

Answer (score 0):

This could be done using an anonymous function

```
r=0.3;
p=0.82;
f=@(theta) (r^2)/2*(2*pi*p-theta+p*sin(theta));
```

then to evaluate the function just use eg: `f(1)`, and to plot it, for example:

```
angles=0:.01:pi;
plot(angles,f(angles))
```

If you don't want to use an anonymous function, then use

```
function funcVal=func(angles)
    r=0.3;
    p=0.82;
    funcVal=(r^2)/2*(2*pi*p-angles+p*sin(angles));
end
```

and call it by

```
angles=0:.01:pi;
plot(angles,func(angles))
```